# "Compress contents to save disk space" option not available for one partition

Tags: compression, windows-server-2003

One of the partitions on our Server 2003 R2 server recently ran out of free disk space.

After freeing up a significant amount of free space (20 GB, which only corresponds to 1.37% of the partition - maybe not enough?), I noticed that the "Compress contents to save disk space" option was greyed out for every file and folder on that partition:

[image]

Does there need to be a certain *percentage* of free space on the drive, rather than *absolute* amount of free space? Or maybe running out of free space caused it to disable this option and it won't return until the system is rebooted?

Just to clarify: this option used to exist on this partition at one point and the partition was, and still is, NTFS formatted. All other NTFS partitions on this drive *do* have a "Compress drive to save disk space" option in the "General" tab but that option does not exist for this particular partition.

I haven't seen this before and couldn't find any information online about it.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this to happen and how can go about fixing it?

Comment: Are you sure the account that you are using has "Full Control" access to that folder ? AFAIK this is a requirement for the option to be available.

Comment: This is a server so I'm logging in as domain admin.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean you have full-control. It only means you can take control if you need it. Check the "effective permissions".

Comment: Aha. Good point. I just checked my effective permissions for this partition and I do indeed have full control. Hmm...

Answer (score 7):

What is the cluster size? NTFS compression only works on volumes with a cluster size of 4k or less.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression.aspx

> Native NTFS compression does not function on volumes where the cluster size is greater than 4KB, but sparse file compression can still be used.

Comment: Good one... Especially since he mentions that it is a HUGE volume.

Comment: But normally the cluster-size isn't changed and it used to work before. Could be someone used fsutil to disable compression. (Do "fsutil behavior query disablecompression" to check that.) Check clustersize with "fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <drive>".

Comment: 20 GB as 1.37% of the total is only a 1.5 TB partition. https://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365 The default cluster size is 4k up to 2TB, but I agree it's not common to change it later.

Comment: This server is virtualized - maybe I should've mentioned it before but I wasn't sure if it was relevant. Does cluster size matter with VMs the same way as with physical machines?

Comment: I do not think that should matter. Checkout of that MSDN link above. There is a screen shot that looks like yours with the checkbox grayed out due to a sparse file getting copied manually. Perhaps your issue is related. I'm sorry, I really don't know why yours is happening. I did some searches and didn't turn up much else.

Comment: You might want to mention 4k clusters are not possible on 18+ terabyte drives, would have saved me 4 weeks of trouble emptying and refilling.